# Generate request token in contao on Maintenance Page

Tags: php, security, contao

I am trying to insert the newsletter form into maintenance page. I am using contao 3.5+ currently. I have connected with api but on newsletter signup page i am trying to send request token as a hidden field which i am not being able to generate on maintenance page specifically.

Currently I am sending the following

```
<input type="hidden" name="REQUEST_TOKEN" value="{{request_token}}" />
```

**The insert tag {{request}} token should have generated a random string like in other pages**. However, it does not seem to work on maintenance page. So, any contao developers out here. Really appreciate if you could me out here.

For newsletter I am using existing `hc_newsletter` plugin from contao repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
\Controller::replaceInsertTags(…)
```

is only executed in the front end. Use something like

```php
<input type="hidden" name="REQUEST_TOKEN" value="<?= REQUEST_TOKEN ?>">
```

instead (depending on how you are echoing the input), i.e. echo the `REQUEST_TOKEN` constant directly.

Comment: Yes found the answer.. Done same thing.. Calling REQUEST_TOKEN global variable seemed to solve the problem .. Thanx anyway..